Installing Fixed Glass Panel on One Piece Shower Unit
We are remodeling the bathroom in my father in laws home.  We purchased a low threshold one piece shower unit.  For easy for cleaning and access, I would like to install a 36-40 inch wide fixed panel on the shower so there are no doors.  Everything I have found shows them installed easily into a shower pan, but only into a tiled wall on the side vs the fiberglass of the one piece.  Is it possible to install this into a one piece shower unit?

That is best asked of the manufacturer of the glass panel.  Generally glass panels are too heavy to be mounted to fiberglass enclosures.

What does "fixed panel" mean here?
